# Animated Sprites blocked by Canvas in Unity

Tags: animation, sprite, game-engine, unity-game-engine, layer

I have managed to animate a series of sprites by dragging a group of sprites into the Hierarchy. However, when I enabled the Canvas, the Canvas was blocking all the sprites. What should I do to display the animation on the Canvas? I have tried adjusting the layers and camera modes, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I understand that you want your sprites to be displayed on top of the UI. You can use 2 cameras and adjust their depths so that one of them displays the layer of the animation (make this one the top camera) and the other one displays the UI layer.

[Use Culling Masks in Camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html)

[How to use Multiple Cameras](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultipleCameras.html)